# Update ScrollView when image is resized (WPF)

Tags: wpf, image, scrollview

I'm doing a graphic editor for a GBA game and I got an image into a ScrollView. When the user click on a NumericUpDown, the image is resized with a magnify factor. I would like my ScrollView to adapt itself to the new size of the image to be able to scroll the entire image. I'm not using the MVVM patter.

Here is portion of my XAML:

```xml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PortraitScrollBar" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Image x:Name="ImagePortrait" Width="280" Height="280" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here also is my function that is called on the ValueChanged event of the NumericUpDown:

```cs
public static void Magnify(ref Image img, WriteableBitmap wBmp, int factor)
{
    img.Source = wBmp.Resize(wBmp.PixelWidth * factor, wBmp.PixelHeight * factor, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.NearestNeighbor);  
}

private void PorMagnifyUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (IsInit)
    {
        Magnify(ref ImagePortrait, currentImage, (int)e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a boundary Height and Width for your ScrollViewer. If content goes out of that bound scrolling should be enabled.